Why is asking for DNF when YUM is specified?
I am running a GHA workflow that uses an Ubuntu 22.04 runner to run an Ansible playbook on an Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance on every step that uses the ansible.builtin.yum module, for example:
- name: 'Install selinux dependency packages'
  ansible.builtin.yum:
    name: '{{ yum_selinux_packages }}'
    state: present
    disable_gpg_check: true
  when: 'os != "amzn2023"'

throws the error:
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"pkg_mgr": "unknown"}, "changed": false, "msg": ["Could not detect which major revision of dnf is in use, which is required to determine module backend.", "You should manually specify use_backend to tell the module whether to use the dnf4 or dnf5 backend})"]}

This happens since I updated the runners (the playbook is the same as in the past) with the latest versions of some tools and also with:
    && rm -rf /home/runner/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible_collections/grafana \
    && rm -rf ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible_collections/community/digitalocean \
    && sudo apt install -y nodejs npm \
    && curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash \
    && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install 20 \
    && sudo npm install npm@latest -g

because there were some vulns Snyk reported and had to be fixed.
So please explain why is asking for dnf even so yum is the default pkg mgr for AL2 and also how those changes in the runner might impact this.
- name: "yum update".                    # this works
  ansible.builtin.shell: 'yum update *'
  become: true

- name: 'Update all yum packages'  # this doesn't
  ansible.builtin.yum:
    name: '*'
    state: latest
  become: true

If I add use_backend: yum the error persists
If I add use_backend: dnf it asks to install python3-dnf
Using the shell module doesn't fix the root cause of the problem and it gets complicated for the selinux block and others so is not a solution.
LE: found out that the Ansible removed the yum module from its latest version. Dnf is not compatible with AL2 so the solution is to use the previous Ansible version.

So from Ansible 10.x version (ansible-core 2.17)  using yum module on operating system using yum package manager such as CentOS 7 and Amazon Linux 2 (AL2) is not possible (and EoL date for CentOS 7 was 30th of June 2024)
Reference:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.17/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.17.rst#removed-features-previously-deprecated:

With the removal of Python 2 support, the yum module and yum action plugin are removed and redirected to dnf.

Workaround is indeed to use Ansible 9.x/ansible-core 2.16, which can be done by using entry like ansible < 10 in requirements file.

Yes. This is exactly what I've done last week. Thanks.
